# Any CDR (call data record) dataset?

Tags: data-request, telecom

I would like to do some analytics on ***CDR data***, preferably mobile, but anything will do.
Ideally I would like to have between 100MB to 10GB of data.

I have been trying to look for this type of data on the web, so far with no luck.

Apparently a lot of interesting studies have been going around academia but I couldn't find anything to download.

Basically I want to experiment with (ideally large) CDRs dataset.  As the CDR layout may vary (e.g. may contain price elements; time of call; duration; position of caller etc.), the analytics I'll do will depend on the data I'll find.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If academics are publishing papers, it wouldn't hurt to ask them for their data sets. You can also ask them how much of their research is publically funded.

Comment: I don't want to appear negative but I do not have a  good experience in asking academics. I was looking for an insurance claim dataset a while ago and I asked help to a prof. in Barcelona who published a lot using the dataset (coming from an insurer with HQ in Barcelona). No answer.  It is true that she made a life long career through that dataset...

Comment: Enzo : as there's info about the position of the caller,  it's possible that the researcher may not be able to release the data to you.  It all depends on what sort of agreements they made to aquire the data.  The fact that they've not responded to you could be another problem, as it means that we've got a situation where the evidence used in research isn't available.  You might be able to get access to the data to validate their analysis, you'd likely have to enter into an agreement that wouldn't give you free use of the data.

Comment: @Enzo - I know it can be frustrating, but think of yourself as a data journalist digging for the story. If not one researcher, try another. It's possible to mask data so in theory a CDR can be anonymous and therefore shared.

Comment: I don't think you're ever going to be successful in this search. You may already know this, but : at a minimum, telecom CDRs are protected via privacy laws - the 4th Amendment in the US; they're the basis for revenue calculations (thus proprietary); and you can figure out criminal acts from the processing of these records (masking the ANI for voice call fraud). Telecoms companies also set their per-minute rates based upon their analysis of these records so they're very unlikely to let anyone in the tent (no matter how small the data set).

Comment: You missed this: http://www.telecomitalia.com/tit/en/bigdatachallenge/contest/dataset.html Perhaps it will open again in the future.

Comment: @philsem Thanks for the TelecomItalia tip!  Let's see if I'll get anywhere with it.  You're right  it is like a journalist chasing a story...

Comment: Hi,
were you able to get your hands of a sample dataset ?
The d4d & telecomitalia challenges are over and I couldn't find their datasets anywhere.

Thanks,

Comment: I searched over all the comments, and links attached but still didn't find relevant Data Bases.
I want anonymized CDR (priority for location column), per person, and not aggregate. long periods is better for my research.
I searched over the ebola research and milano challenge - but they are aggregated.
can't find the D4D challenge data.
and generators are nice but I prefer real CDR. do someone knows something that can fit my request? thanks all.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5756)

Answer (score 8):

Try with d4d challenge from orange Senegal:

http://www.d4d.orange.com/en/home

"2.5B anonymized records of 5 million mobile phones"

Comment: Great news!  I was aware of the initial challenge (but I got to know about it when it was too late). At least now I'm in time to apply.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated link? http://www.d4d.orange.com/en/Accueil

Answer (score 6):

The [Flowminder.org](http://www.flowminder.org/) project has made available anonymized West African CDRs related to the Ebola crisis. You can read more at the [WorldPop page](http://www.worldpop.org.uk/ebola/).

> Here we provide version 1 Flowminder (www.flowminder.org) human mobility models for West Africa, built on WorldPop population data, to support ongoing efforts to control the ebola outbreak. Before downloading any data, please read the documention carefully as it provides details on the datasets and models provided through the links below.

- [Documentation (.pdf)](http://www.worldpop.org.uk/ebola/Flowminder-Mobility-Data-21.08.14.pdf)
- [Mobility Data (.zip)](http://www.worldpop.org.uk/ebola/mobility_data/mobility-data-1stSept14.zip)
- [Spatial Data (.7z)](http://www.worldpop.org.uk/ebola/Spatial_Data.7z)

[image]

> Worldpop datasets are licensed under the
>   [Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)

Comment: Great post.  I'll look into this project.  It is really interesting.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1841/1511) was posted by [@peterm](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/2550/peterm), and I think it could be useful for you project.

[**Call Detail Record Generator**](http://www.gedis-studio.com/online-call-detail-records-cdr-generator.html)

> Our call detail records (CDR) generator is developed with GEDIS Studio and is available on-line. To use it, you need to register for an account at http://www.data-generator.com and import into your private workspace the Telecom project available from the shared workspace.

Comment: Links are not valid

Answer (score 4):

I wrote one Java [utility](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/cdr-data-generator) to generate the data.

> Utility to generate Telecom Call Detail/Data Records Generator

Comment: Great utility.  I've starred the project on github and I'll test it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

While looking for Dataset for call data in the telecom domain, I bumped into 
the following STRUCTURED Data samples spanning call logs/comapliants related features -

1. https://data.dublinked.ie/dataset/b40eabb2-52db-42b1-aafb-3cfa06bac5eb/resource/e83c8cfb-e73a-4e33-8c2e-3f95cc3bba46/download/dcccustomerservicerequests010111-170713.xls
2. http://www.iainpardoe.com/teaching/dsc433/data/Churn.xls
3. https://data.gov.uk/dataset/telecommunications-market-quarterly-data-tables/datapackage.zip
4. https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/api/views/v2ei-xfce/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
5. http://www.sgi.com/tech/mlc/db/churn.data

<strike>I have more links, but my "reputation" at this sub-domain doesn't allow me to post more links.</strike>

Comment: Thanks! Could you try to paste some additional link as reply to this comment?

Comment: Added ! Courtesy - the upvotes :) !
Please note that the 3rd link (.zip) is more concerned with call logs & the related financial Data.

Answer (score 3):

While I had completely missed the TelecomItalia 2014 big data challenge kindly mentioned by @philshem (many thanks again to bring this to my attention), I just spotted that the dataset created for the challenge has just now been classed as Open Data and made available to the general public.

If you want to download the data, you need to get to:
**https://dandelion.eu**

Then click on `Product` to select `Open Data`

The site requires a registration but the download of the data is free.

Thanks to all the people that have / are supporting this search!

Comment: The direct link is https://dandelion.eu/datamine/open-big-data/ — the six "Telecommunications" datasets might be of interest.

Comment: They are aggregated unfortunately. You won't do something interesting on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers are out of date. Here I found useful resources from Harvard & sobigdata sites. In order to use these resources, you have to accept their policy statemnt.

- https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/EGZHFV
- https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/QLCABU
- https://sobigdata.d4science.org/catalogue-sobigdata?path=/dataset/call_data_record_district_of_pisa_2013_october
- https://sobigdata.d4science.org/catalogue-sobigdata?path=/dataset/call_data_record_pisa_livorno_firenze_lucca_2014