# Download a sample database of calls in telecommunication

Tags: data-request, telecom

I am trying to do a project for data analysis based on the details of calls stored in Call Details Record (CDR) of telecommunications industry. It will take some time to obtain the real data, and before that I want to work on some sample data. Is there any source which provides a very simple CDR database?

I would prefer voice calls but it can be database of other actions like GPRS usage. If CDR is not available anything related to telecom is OK.

Comment: How can a question from 2013 be a duplicate of one from 2014?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a CDR sample:

```
MSIDN:IMSI:IMEI:PLAN:CALL_TYPE:CORRESP_TYPE:CORRESP_ISDN:DURATION:TIME:DATE 
068373748102;208100167682477;351905149071;PLAN1;MOC;CUST1;0612287077;247;12:07:12;01/01/2012 
068373748102;208100167682477;351905149071;PLAN1;MTC;CUST2;0600000001;300;12:15:09;01/01/2012 
068373748102;208100167682477;351905149071;PLAN1;SMS-MO;CUST1;0613637193;0;12:18:18;01/01/2012 
068373748102;208100167682477;351905149071;PLAN1;SMS-MT;CUST1;0612899062;0;12:21:07;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;MOC;CUST1;0612283725;90;12:00:00;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;MOC;CUST1;0613069656;82;12:02:27;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;MOC;CUST1;0613481951;78;12:04:41;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;MTC;CUST2;0600000001;92;12:07:13;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;MTC;CUST2;0600000002;94;12:09:40;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;MTC;CUST1;0612063352;114;12:12:40;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;SMS-MO;CUST1;0613103364;0;12:13:42;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;SMS-MO;CUST1;0613751973;0;12:14:44;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;SMS-MO;CUST1;0613672843;0;12:15:44;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;SMS-MT;CUST1;0612769488;0;12:16:42;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;SMS-MT;CUST1;0613164676;0;12:17:39;01/01/2012 
065978198280;208100310191699;356008289837;PLAN3;SMS-MT;CUST1;0613399901;0;12:18:39;01/01/2012 
067599860569;208120276653317;353297808290;PLAN2;MOC;CUST1;0612089847;116;12:00:00;01/01/2012
```

Answer (score 3):

Have the same problem need:

1. anon cdr
2. cell/base stations locations and their lac/cid to project
   anon data on map.

Telecom Italia provides aggregated dataset and there are not too much stuff to do with it.

You can find related discussion here:  [Any CDR (call data record) dataset?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1670) and source site: http://dandelion.eu

Answer (score 2):

There is no fully open telecom sample that I'm aware of, this kind of data has been opened in the past for research purposes or as part of data mining contests - such as [this paper based on one from Orange](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.0137) and a more recent one by [Telecom Italia](http://www.telecomitalia.com/tit/en/bigdatachallenge.html).