# People Mobility Data

Tags: data-request

I am student, doing research on people mobility. Is there any dataset that I can use to benchmark my work (kind of a framework); I am looking for any kind of data (CDR Dataset, GPS/Location data .. ) ?

Answer (score 1):

You may have already seen it but this question from last year has a few CDR datasets, someone of them were released in connection with competitions so I'm not sure if they're all still available. Also it appears they use different levels of aggregation which may render them useless for your research.

[Any CDR (call data record) dataset?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/any-cdr-call-data-record-dataset)