# User complaint/review description for running nlp-ner on telecom(preferably) data

Tags: data-request, nlp, telecom, unstructured-data

I am looking for Consumer complaint/review description data which is not generated from automatic logs but **manually entered** by the end-user/customer-support.

The objective is to run the **Stanford NLP-NER** tool on the user description for determining the **Location, Organization, Faulty Device,** etc related to the complaint.
I have been struggling for 2-3 days to explore and have found some Telco data, but all of the Data is STRUCTURED. See my answer on [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/9720/13779).

The key elements of the data I need are -

> 1. UNSTRUCTURED description by the end-user or by customer-support.
> 2. Data can be in the form of either of 'complete sentences' or phrases(say comma separated/semi-colon separated data).
>      A hypothetical **example** (just for the sake of clarity and not restricted to the following format) of tow of the concerned columns among the rest of the user/caller info -
>
> **Fault Description** - "I am calling from New York; staying at Hotel Marriot Marquis; Please help asap - my phone not working."
>
> **Fault Resolution** - "System connection established in New York; Hotel Marriot Marquis; Issue resolved by on-site visit - problem in region multiplexer..bla bla."

I believe this problem would make for an interesting application in the Telecom domain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for similar. Did you check reddit forums? Reddit has a decent API for scraping. Also many telcos have their own customer complaint forums.

Also structured, but I came across the fact that MeaningCloud provides some pre-trained categorization models for Telco vertical
https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/documentation/predefined/deep-categorization-models/voc-telco

Let me know if you found anything else!